# netsh http show sslcert does not show certificate information

Tags: ssl, owin, netsh

I have a OWIN hosted Web API 2 that I am trying to get to work with SSL. I have installed the certificate on the server. I can see it under `Certificates - Current user\Trusted Root Certication Authorities\Certification`.
I can see the thumbprint in the details of the certificate. Seems good so far.
I do not have IIS on this server. I am trying to bind port 443 to it via command line. However, I cannot see the `applicationID` when I do the command.

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

In fact nothing comes up. I am trying to get the `applicationID` and then use the following command to bind port 443 to it.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=baf9926b466e8565217b5e6287c97973dcd54874 appid={ab3c58f7-8316-42e3-bc6e-771d4ce4b201}
```

Any idea why netsh http show sslcert might not be returning data back to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it'd give you error reason why it failed to add sslcert entry. But I believe you must import the certificate under 'Local Computer - Personal' certificate store.

Also, I am assuming your certificate has the private key in it. If so, it would show small key icon on top of certificate icon. Note that this is important for it to work with OWIN.